# Android: How to create a receiver that listen any click to status bar drop down?

Tags: android, statusbar

I'd like to know how to create a receiver that listen when the user drag down the status bar.

There is a way to do this?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know how to create a receiver that listen when the user drag down the status bar.

There is no way to do that. You can only listen to things that are broadcasted and dragging down the statusbar is not an important event that needs to be broadcasted.

Comment: The real problem for me is to create a receiver that listen when the user change system settings...do you know where I can find a list of action that I can put on Intent-filter?

Comment: there is no broadcast for that as well. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html is the best list I know of.