# Android: listener on the status bar notification

Tags: android, listener, statusbar

Is there a way to listen to the status bar notification when it is being pulled down?

Answer (score 3):

**1. For detecting status bar changes: you can register a listener to get notified of system UI visibility changes**

So to register the listener in your activity:

```
// Detecting if the user swipe from the top down to the phone 
// screen to show up the status bar (without showing the notification area)

View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    // The system bars are visible.

                } else {
                    // The system bars are NOT visible.

                }
            }
        });
```

check out this [from documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility) for more detail

**2. For detecting if the user pulls down the notification area of the status bar: override `onWindowFocusChanged()` in your activity**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    if (hasFocus) { // hasFocus is true
        // the user pushed the notification bar back to the top
        Log.i("Tag", "Notification bar is pushed up");

    } else { // hasFocus is false
        // the user pulls down the notification bar
        Log.i("Tag", "Notification bar is pulled down");
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

}
```

check out the solution of Stephan Palmer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689497/how-to-tell-the-activity-has-been-covered-by-the-notification-area)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on [Notification.Builder setDeleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) (since api level 11).

There is also [Notification deleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) (since api level 1)

Comment: there was link in documentation to api level 1 see my update.

Comment: but it is not what I want. I want to know if the user has pulled down the status bar to the end of the screen or not.

Comment: cool misunderstunding :). Why do you need this kind of functionality? IMO there is no such notification. You can try to find it in Android code http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Comment: I can not listen to the status bar as I wish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373187/android-how-to-create-a-receiver-that-listen-any-click-to-status-bar-drop-down

Comment: @MarekR: He is asking about the receiver when the notification bar is pulled down, not the clear action.